# Adding PostBackTriggers and AsyncPostBackTriggers to UpdatePanel for dynamically-generated grandchild controls

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, asp.net-3.5

I have a page with a ScriptManager, a generic HTML drop-down list (`<select>`), and an UpdatePanel.  The UpdatePanel contains a PlaceHolder (for now).  During Page_Load, a number of user controls are added to the PlaceHolder (really, it's several instances of the same user control).  The number to add is not known until the page loads, so they do need to be loaded dynamically.  The drop-down list is populated with the same number of menu items, and there is javascript on the page also (using jQuery) to show only one of the controls at a time depending on the state of the drop-down list.

Each user control has two buttons that should generate an asynchronous postback, a drop-down list that should generate an asynchronous postback on a change in selected value, and a button that should generate a synchronous postback.  If I was not generating the controls dynamically, and if there was only one control, the structure would be something like:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="asyncButton1" runat="server" Text="Button1"
                    onclick="asyncButton1_Click" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="asyncDropDown" ruant="server" AutoPostBack="true"
                    OnSelectedIndexChanged="asyncDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:Button ID="asyncButton2" runat="server" Text="Button2"
                    OnClick="asyncButton2_Click" />
        <asp:Button ID="syncButton" runat="server" Text="SyncButton"
                    OnClick="syncButton_Click" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="asyncButton1" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="asyncButton2" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="asyncDropDown"
            EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="syncButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Of course, all the controls inside the ContentTemplate would actually be part of each user control.

Adding the triggers on the server side does not seem to work because no ControlID seems to help the UpdatePanel find the relevant controls.  I can use either the control's ID or the control's UniqueID, and it does not work, and I get an error along the lines of

```
A control with ID 'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ctl01$asyncButton1' could not be
found for the trigger in UpdatePanel 'myUpdatePanel'.
```

So, I wonder if I need to register the triggers in the client instead using ASP.NET Ajax.  I found [this page](http://vincexu.blogspot.com/2009/06/dynamically-register-updatepanel.html) that basically explains how.  However, I do not know how to get the EventName taken into consideration.  The examples I have seen so far have merely been adding button clicks, but I don't know how to handle the SelectedIndexChanged event from the DropDownList.

Any help here?  Are there examples out there I have missed?  It doesn't help, of course, that the method in the link I gave appears to be "unofficial," so I don't see any MSDN documents on the subject.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using .net framework 4.0? I ask because now you have more control over Control.ClientID: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.clientid.aspx

Comment: @Tim No, this has to be .NET 3.5 for now.

Comment: tagged as 3.5. I'm gonna go in for a closer look later.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My suggestion would be to pull all your controls inclusive this UpdatePanel out of this UpdatePanel into an UserControl. Define events in your usercontrol that are raised when the buttons are clicked or the Dropdown's selected index get changed. Handle these events in your page that holds the Placeholder(in a single UpdatePanel,conditional,without triggers). Call the Update-method of the main update panel manually if you add UserControls.

To clarify what i mean have a look at following example:

**Main-page aspx:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="Upd1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
  </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Codebehind:**

```
  Private Property UserControlCount() As Int32
        Get
            If ViewState("UserControlCount") Is Nothing Then
                ViewState("UserControlCount") = 1
            End If
            Return DirectCast(ViewState("UserControlCount"), Int32)
        End Get
        Set(ByVal value As Int32)
            ViewState("UserControlCount") = value
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        recreateUserControls()
    End Sub

    Private Sub recreateUserControls()
        For i As Int32 = 1 To Me.UserControlCount
            Dim uc As DynamicControls = DirectCast(Me.LoadControl("DynamicControls.ascx"), DynamicControls)
            uc.ID = "DynamicControls_" & i
            Addhandlers(uc)
            Me.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc)
        Next
    End Sub

    Private Sub Addhandlers(ByVal uc As DynamicControls)
        AddHandler uc.asyncButton1Clicked, AddressOf ucAsyncButton1Clicked
        AddHandler uc.asyncButton2Clicked, AddressOf ucAsyncButton2Clicked
        AddHandler uc.syncButtonClicked, AddressOf ucSyncButtonClicked
        AddHandler uc.asyncDropDownSelectedIndexChanged, AddressOf ucAsyncDropDownSelectedIndexChanged
    End Sub

    Private Sub addUserControl()
        Me.UserControlCount += 1

        Dim uc As DynamicControls = DirectCast(Me.LoadControl("DynamicControls.ascx"), DynamicControls)
        uc.ID = "DynamicControls_" & Me.UserControlCount
        Addhandlers(uc)
        Me.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(uc)

        Upd1.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ucAsyncButton1Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        'only to demonstrate how to add control dynamically and update the UpdatePanel'
        addUserControl()
        Me.Upd1.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ucAsyncButton2Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ucSyncButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ucAsyncDropDownSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    End Sub
```

**ascx which holds your controls:**

```
<%@ Control Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="DynamicControls.ascx.vb" Inherits="AJAXEnabledWebApplication1.DynamicControls" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="asp" %>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional"
                 ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox1" runat="server" />
        <asp:TextBox ID="textBox2" runat="server" />
        <asp:Button ID="asyncButton1" runat="server" Text="Button1" />
        <asp:DropDownList ID="asyncDropDown" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" />
        <asp:Button ID="asyncButton2" runat="server" Text="Button2" />
        <asp:Button ID="syncButton" runat="server" Text="SyncButton" />
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="asyncButton1" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="asyncButton2" EventName="Click" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="asyncDropDown" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="syncButton" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Codebehind of UserControl:**

```
Public Partial Class DynamicControls
    Inherits System.Web.UI.UserControl

    Public Event asyncButton1Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Public Event asyncButton2Clicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Public Event syncButtonClicked(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    Public Event asyncDropDownSelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

    Private Sub asyncButton1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles asyncButton1.Click
        RaiseEvent asyncButton1Clicked(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub asyncButton2_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles asyncButton2.Click
        RaiseEvent asyncButton2Clicked(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub syncButton_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles syncButton.Click
        RaiseEvent syncButtonClicked(sender, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub asyncDropDown_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles asyncDropDown.SelectedIndexChanged
        RaiseEvent asyncDropDownSelectedIndexChanged(sender, e)
    End Sub
End Class
```

On this way you won't have problems with ClientID's.

**Addition:**
If you need access to the controls of your UserControls in the event-handlers, use one of following two options:

1. cast the sender's NamingContainer to the userControl's type: `Dim uc As DynamicControls = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, Control).NamingContainer, DynamicControls)`
2. replace all occurences of `(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)` with `(uc as DynamicControls)`. On this way the reference of your UserControl is added to the event as parameter and you could access public properties of it from the page, f.e.:

   ```
   dim txt1 as String = uc.Text1
   ```

If you have exposed a property Text1 in the UserControl:

```
Public Property Text1() As String
     Get
         Return textBox1.Text
     End Get
     Set(ByVal value As String)
         textBox1.Text = value
     End Set
 End Property
```

The second option is the cleanest and most readable way.

**Update**:
According to your comment: you should place the UpdateProgress in the UserControl inside of the UpdatePanel that gets updated. Remember to set the [AssociatedUpdatePanelID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updateprogress.associatedupdatepanelid.aspx) correctly. For example:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UdpForm" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"  >
  <ContentTemplate>
    <asp:panel ID="FormPanel" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress1" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UdpForm" DisplayAfter="0" >
            <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="progress">
                <asp:Image ID="ImgProgress1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader-arrows.gif" ToolTip="loading..." />&nbsp;please wait...
            </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
         </asp:UpdateProgress>     
         <asp:FormView ID="FormView1"  runat="server" DefaultMode="ReadOnly"  >
             <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
             <EditItemTemplate></EditItemTemplate>
             <InsertItemTemplate></InsertItemTemplate>
             <EmptyDataTemplate>
             </EmptyDataTemplate>
             <PagerTemplate >
             </PagerTemplate>
        </asp:FormView>
     </asp:panel>
  </contenttemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel> 

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdContent" runat="server" UpdateMode="conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false"  >
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:Panel ID="PnlMain" runat="server">
        <asp:UpdateProgress ID="UpdateProgress2" DynamicLayout="true" runat="server" AssociatedUpdatePanelID="UpdContent" DisplayAfter="0" >
            <ProgressTemplate>
            <div class="progress">
                <asp:Image ID="ImgProgress1" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/ajax-loader-arrows.gif" ToolTip="loading..." />&nbsp;please wait...
            </div>
            </ProgressTemplate>
         </asp:UpdateProgress>

         Content

   </asp:Panel>
 </ContentTemplate> 
   <Triggers ></Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've debugging the app, and I think this more-or-less works.  Do you happen to know how to get an UpdateProgress to display when one of the triggers is, well, triggered in this situation?  I have tried placing the UpdateProgress in the page and in the control (outside the actual UpdatePanel in both cases), and in neither case does it appear.

Comment: @Andrew; i have updated my answer with a sample(to simplify without any content)that works for me. It has two updatepanels inside of an UserControl. Adjust it to your requirements.