# jQuery autocomplete trigger return on select

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, autocomplete

I searched a lot of place but i do not understand jquery enough to sucessfully use the answers i find.

I need to doubletab return to trigger my textbox *ontextchanged* event so my gridview is updating.

My autocomplete script is functioning proberly and looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="ja">
    $(function () {
        $('#tbCompany').autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Autocomplete.asmx/GetCompanyNames",
                    data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                    success: function (result) {                          
                        response(result.d);                            
                    },                       
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                    }
                });
            },
            minLength: 0
        });
    });
</script>


<asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="tbCompany" placeholder="Bitte Ausfüllen" ClientIDMode="static" OnTextChanged="tbCompany_TextChanged" Width="400px" Visible="false" TabIndex="1" />


 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
      <ContentTemplate>
           <asp:GridView ID="gvVerzeichniss" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowCommand="gvVerzeichniss_RowCommand" CssClass="mGrid" AlternatingRowStyle-CssClass="alt" PagerStyle-CssClass="pgr" GridLines="None" ShowHeader="false" style="width: 1300px !important;">
                <Columns>
                        <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Link" Text="view" CommandName="view" HeaderText="Show" Visible="true" ControlStyle-Width="40px" ControlStyle-ForeColor="#428bca"/>
                        <asp:CheckBoxField HeaderText="Active" ReadOnly="false" DataField="Active" ControlStyle-Width="10px" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </ContentTemplate>
        <Triggers>
            <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbCompany"/>
        </Triggers>
  </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

It should trigger the the *ontextchanged* event of the textbox on select of an item, but i dont know how to write that.

Comment: share you html code also.

Comment: forgot that, eddited it.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you were sending ajax call inside autocomplete while autocomplete bind after data received from service.

*Your `result.d` must have `json` data.*

If I understand right you looking for something like this

```
<script type="text/javascript" lang="ja">
    $(function () { 
          $.ajax({
                url: "Autocomplete.asmx/GetCompanyNames",
                data: "{ 'searchTerm': '" + request.term + "' }",
                type: "POST",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
                success: function (result) {                          
                  $('#'+'<%= tbCompany.ClientID %>').autocomplete({
                    source: result.d,
                    minLength: 0
                  });                        
                },                       
                error: function (result) {
                    alert('There is a problem processing your request');
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: missing ',' after result.d

Comment: I have update my answer please see. if you are using classic asp.net then you need to select element like this `$('#'+'<%= tbCompany.ClientID %>')`. which brackets?

Comment: Ahh yes i forgot that. added. :)

Comment: i added my gridview code which should be updated its not working at the point stll need to hit enter

Comment: change this line in update panel `<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="tbCompany" EventName="TextChanged"/>`

Comment: you can take help of this example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4742208/adding-postbacktriggers-and-asyncpostbacktriggers-to-updatepanel-for-dynamically

Comment: still need to hit enter after select before its updated:/ couldn´t find something, forgot the event  but before it was an postback trigger